# call multiple api in loop with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

*Scenario:* I have a list of url, i want to call each within saga generator function in redux and gather the response of all in an array and pass it to another  functon.

*Input:*

```
const urlLists = [
            {app:"Application1",url:'/health/up'},
            {app:"Application2",url:'/health/up'},
            {app:"Application3",url:'/health/down'},
            {app:"Application4",url:'/health/up'}]
```

- when I call these api's their response is like: {"status":"up"} or {"status":"down"}

*Output:*

```
[
            {app:"Application1",status:'up'},
            {app:"Application2",status:'up'},
            {app:"Application3",status:'down'},
            {app:"Application4",status:'down'}]
```

*What I tried:* https://pastebin.com/twxhVkFw

can any body help...

*Error:* [image]

Comment: The "what I tried" part is blank.  Please share your saga code.

Comment: Hi jmargolisvt, thanks for your reply, I have added the link

Comment: It is preferred on SO that you publish you code directly in the question.  Links die over time, but your question may remain useful.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me..

```js
export function* fetchHelthSaga(action) {
    yield put(actions.fetchHealthStart());
    yield action.urlList.map(host => call(updateResponseList, host))  
}

function* updateResponseList(host){
    let r = {};
    try {
        const resp = yield api.get(host.url)
        r = { appName: host.app, status: resp.data.status, isHostResponding: true };
        yield put(actions.fetchHealthSuccess(r));
    } catch (error) {
        r = { appName: host.app, status: "down", isHostResponding: false };
        const errResp = {error:error,response:r};
        yield put(actions.fetchHealthFail(errResp));
    }
}
```